# How SSH work between an Intel's Galileo board and my laptop?

Tags: ssh, ethernet

I'm very newbie at network issues and I'm using my laptop and a SSH connection to access my Intel's Galileo board directories. To achieve this, the tutorial says I must connect Galileo to my router using a Ethernet cable. I would like to know why I can't connect Galileo to my laptop through Ethernet cable since my laptop and my router uses the same network. Sorry for misconceptions.

Comment: The real question is: What I"m supposed to do to setup a SSH connection using a Ethernet connection between Galileo and laptop, not between Galileo and router, as my tutorial said. I tried and achieved nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "simplicity".

You absolutely *can* connect your Galileo to your laptop, but you have to set your laptop up in order to do so, your router on the other hand is already set up correctly.

Essentially the Galileo is going to be expecting a DHCP server at the end of the ethernet cable, without this is will fall back to some [link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) in the 169.254.0.0/16 range.  You will probably not know what address the Galileo gets without some kind of screen or display and keyboard to run `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` (I can't remember which command is Linux and which is Windows at the moment).

You can run a [DHCP server](http://www.dhcpserver.de/cms/) on your laptop, which fixes the issue of discovery and can even quickly tell you what IP address the Galileo has without much investigation, but you then have to mess around with the network connection.  The IP address on that network connection will need to be static and outside of the address range of the WiFi network if you want to connect to the internet at the same time, which is a pain if you ever want to use that wired connection to connect to the router as you'll have to reset it back to DHCP allocated.  You also want to make sure that the DHCP server is not being blocked by the Windows firewall.

You'll also need to setup your laptop to act as a gateway and share its internet connection to the Galileo  if you ever want to download updates or browse the internet on that machine. This functionality used to be included in Windows, but I do not know if it still is, it used to be called Internet Connection Sharing.

If you let the router do the work you remove all the pain of setting up your laptop network configuration, and you get indication of the device address from the router configuration pages.  The Galileo gets an address via DHCP as it expects and everything (internet included) "just works".

So if you never need to reconfigure the laptop wired connection, can set up a DHCP server and internet gateway on the laptop then it is perfectly possible to connect the two machines directly. If all that sounds like a hassle then just connect to the router and let that do all the setup for you.